# Business Continuity Active\Active Websphere MQ cluster

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, ibm-mq, mq

I'm very new in this field, and I have not experienced WMQ, but I need to do a business case:

1. In order to make Business continuity in Active\Active mode for an application, I suppose I have two datacenters.
2. Both DC1 and DC2 are Active.
3. Database are synchronized
4. The application server is synchronized.

Then I get High Availability.

Problem is that I do not know how to manage WMQ.

Because this application X  is in communication with other Application Y and Z, When I put this application in Cluster I have to put in cluster also WebSphere MQ? if yes, can you please help me how to implement high-level architecture?

And let me know if there are some application constraints regarding queues?

Below is how I imagine the, how it should be designed.
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3JGx.png)

Comment: Look up IBM MQ 9.1 and RDQM.  You could have and instance in each DC with the other DC anything as failover.

Comment: Hi thank you but WebSphere MQ is deployed on AIX, then RDQM could not be useful in my case. as you should know RDQM has a limitation, it is used only in Linux platform.

Comment: That is understood,  but with no detail to go on I it was not eliminated.

Comment: Yes JoshMc, you are right. Do you have some advice? or if you want more info I can provide it. Basically, I am trying to do BC Active / Active for  applications, (Whith adding new DC) then I need the methodology which will help me to manage WebSphere MQ in Active/Active. i finde this solution, but it is Active / Passive: [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRLD6_7.0.1/com.ibm.omegamon.mes.doc_7.0.1/c_pre_activeactive_AIX.html)

Comment: Instead of RDQM use replication at the storage level ex SRDF.